# How to flush the io buffer in Erlang?

Tags: input, erlang, buffer, flush

How do you flush the io buffer in Erlang?

For instance:

```
> io:format("hello"),
> io:format(user, "hello").
```

[This post](http://www.nabble.com/flushing-IO-td17208130.html) seems to indicate that there is no clean solution.

Is there a better solution than in that post?

Comment: Sorry I have no answer but a question. I'm incredibly curious to why you would want to flush the io buffer, so; Why? :)

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible with the current io server implementation. Your link is broken, but this one refers to a problem caused by the lack of flush operations: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2011-April/057492.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly other than properly implementing a flush "command" in the io/kernel subsystems *and* making sure that the low level drivers that implement the actual io support such a command you really have to simply rely on the system quiescing before closing. A failing I think.

Have a look at io.erl/io_lib.erl in stdlib and file_io_server.erl/prim_file.erl in kernel for the gory details.

As an example, in file_io_server (which effectively takes the request from io/io_lib and routes it to the correct driver), the command types are:

```
{put_chars,Chars}
{get_until,...}
{get_chars,...}
{get_line,...}
{setopts, ...}
```

(i.e. no flush)!

As an alternative you could of course always close your output (which would force a flush) after every write. A logging module I have does something like this every time and it doesn't appear to be that slow (it's a gen_server with the logging received via cast messages):

```
  case file:open(LogFile, [append]) of
    {ok, IODevice} ->
    io:fwrite(IODevice, "~n~2..0B ~2..0B ~4..0B, ~2..0B:~2..0B:~2..0B: ~-8s : ~-20s : ~12w : ",
          [Day, Month, Year, Hour, Minute, Second, Priority, Module, Pid]),
    io:fwrite(IODevice, Msg, Params),
    io:fwrite(IODevice, "~c", [13]),
    file:close(IODevice);
```

Comment: Not that I have ever done it, but from my understanding implementing an io server is not that complex, especially as you can use io_lib for some of the more complex requests. I think you are on to something with the file module, using the file:sync/1 call one can sync the output explicitly. It will just not be done using an io-call, but a custom message, unless one tie it to the io:nl(IO) request.

Answer (score 0):

```
io:put_chars(<<>>)
```

at the end of the script works for me.

Answer (score -6):

you could run

```
flush().
```

from the shell, or try

```
flush()->
receive
    _ -> flush()
after 0 -> ok
end.
```

That works more or less like a C flush.

Comment: This flushes the process mailbox and not the io buffer.

Comment: @Fonz, I suggest to remove your answer, as it is irrelevant, take care!